# PeopleSoft Application Engine debugging - any way to pre-set breakpoints?

Tags: debugging, batch-processing, peoplesoft

I am using Application Engine in debugging mode.  Works well, but every single time I need to re-specify my breakpoints from scratch (yes, aware of history scrolling via up/down arrow, not what I want).

Here's a command script, **runAE.cmd**, I wrote to automate the launch:

`"C:\Program Files\PeopleSoft-PT852\bin\client\winx86\psae.exe" -CT MICROSFT -CD MYDB -CO MYUSER -CP %pwd% -R MYRUNCTLID  -AI TL_TIMEADMIN  -DEBUG Y`

This is a session of me getting started:

```
Application Engine Debugger - enter command or type ? for help.

TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step010L> b
(S)et, (U)nset, or (L)ist? s
Program [TL_TIMEADMIN]: TL_TA_RULES
Section [MAIN]: COPE54
Step    [Step010L]: T01

Breakpoint set at TL_TA_RULES.COPE54.T01

TL_TIMEADMIN.MAIN.Step010L> b
(S)et, (U)nset, or (L)ist? s
Program [TL_TIMEADMIN]: TL_TA_RULES
Section [MAIN]: CUSTBKPY
Step    [Step010L]: Step20

Breakpoint set at TL_TA_RULES.CUSTBKPY.STEP20
```

So, what I thought was to feed the initial breakpoints via a **breakpoints.txt** file.

```
b
s
TL_TA_RULES
COPE54
T01
b
s
TL_TA_RULES
CUSTBKPY
Step20
```

and then launch the whole thing as `runAE.cmd < breakpoints.txt` (basically redirect input from the breakpoints file).

This really messes things up with the Debugger complaining that it doesn't understand the command and then looping on it - i.e. it doesn't just complain for the 10-12 lines in my breakpoints file, it remains stuck on `Invalid command, press ? for help` till I **CTRL-C** the whole sorry mess.